# How Do I Include ForeignKey in django-rest-framework POST

Tags: python, django, api, post, django-rest-framework

So I have tried to make a browsable API via `django-rest-framework (DRF)`, but I have had some issues nesting serializers. So far, I am able to include the `Sport` and `Category` fields/foreignkeys into my `Article`, but when I try to `POST` via the API, I get an error saying as follows:

> Got a `TypeError` when calling `Article.objects.create()`. This may be because you have a writable field on the serializer class that is not a valid argument to `Article.objects.create()`. You may need to make the field read-only, or override the ArticleSerializer.create() method to handle this correctly.
>   Original exception text was: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'ArticleSport'.

Here are my files:

**models.py**

```
[...]

class ArticleSport(TimeStampedModel):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False)
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='title', unique=True, always_update=True)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', blank=True, null=True, related_name='children')  # TODO: Add on_delete?

    uuid = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True, editable=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{0}'.format(self.title)

    #class Meta:  # TODO: Migrate live
        #unique_together = ('title', 'parent')


class ArticleCategory(TimeStampedModel):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False)
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='title', unique=True, always_update=True)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', blank=True, null=True, related_name='children')  # TODO: Add on_delete?

    uuid = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True, editable=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{0}'.format(self.title)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'article categories'
        #unique_together = ('title', 'parent')  # TODO: Migrate live


class Article(TimeStampedModel):
    DEFAULT_FEATURED_IMAGE = settings.STATIC_URL + 'images/defaults/default-featured-image.png'

    title = models.CharField(max_length=160, blank=False)
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='title', unique=True, always_update=True)
    sport = models.ForeignKey(ArticleSport, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='articleAsArticleSport')
    category = models.ForeignKey(ArticleCategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='articleAsArticleCategory')
    featured_image = models.ImageField(upload_to=PathAndUniqueFilename('featured-images/'), blank=True)
    featured_image_caption = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    views = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    uuid = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True, editable=False)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('main:article_specific', args=[self.slug])  # TODO: Remove if standalone pages are removed

    def get_featured_image(self):
        if self.featured_image:
            return self.featured_image.url
        else:
            return self.DEFAULT_FEATURED_IMAGE

    def get_comment_count(self):
        return ArticleComment.objects.filter(article=self).count()

    def __str__(self):
        return '{0}'.format(self.title)

[...]
```

**urls.py**

```
[...]

class ArticleSportSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ArticleSport
        fields = ('id', 'title', 'parent', 'created', 'modified')


class ArticleCategorySerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ArticleCategory
        fields = ('id', 'title', 'parent', 'created', 'modified')


class ArticleSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    sport = ArticleSportSerializer(read_only=True)
    sport_id = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=ArticleSport.objects.all(), write_only=True)
    category = ArticleCategorySerializer(read_only=True)
    category_id = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=ArticleCategory.objects.all(), write_only=True)
    modified = serializers.HiddenField(default=timezone.now())  #TODO: Figure out how to implement this

    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = ('id', 'title', 'sport', 'sport_id', 'category', 'category_id', 'featured_image', 'featured_image_caption', 'views', 'created', 'modified')

[...]
```

Sample POST to API:

```
{
    "title": "This is a test Title",
    "sport_id": 1,
    "category_id": 1,
    "featured_image": null,
    "featured_image_caption": "",
    "views": null,
    "modified": null
}
```

Comment: Why don't you send primary key instead of the whole model?

Comment: I'm very new to DRF, how would I go about what you are suggesting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I was able to answer this question by using some of `Carter_Smith`'s advice - I am not 100% sure why this worked, but I added this `create()` method to my `ArticleSerializer`, and it worked:

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    # Override default `.create()` method in order to properly add `sport` and `category` into the model
    sport = validated_data.pop('sport_id')
    category = validated_data.pop('category_id')
    article = Article.objects.create(sport=sport, category=category, **validated_data)
    return article
```

My guess is that the `PrimaryKeyRelatedField()` tries to resolve `sport_id` and `category_id` as kwarg fields based on their name, when they should be just `sport` and `category`, and so overriding `.create()` allows you to fix that, while still allowing for a `read_only` field for `sport` and `category`. Hope this helps anyone else who has the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

You need to override the serializer's `create` method to accommodate your `POST` request. This probably isn't what you're looking for, but you haven't included your sample request so we haven't got much to go off of.

This would've been a comment had I been of high enough reputation.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I updated my question with the sample POST request. If you could show me an example of overriding the `create` method, it would help me immensely.

Comment: What happens if you remove the serializer fields? Can you post then?

Comment: If I try to remove `sport_id` and `category_id`, I get an error saying `null value in column "category_id" violates not-null constraint` (since it's required)

Comment: That shouldn't be happening.... I'm not asking you to remove these fields from the POST request. I'm asking you to remove them from the serializer `ArticleSerializer` - They're not needed unless you truly want `write_only`. But what I'm wondering is if the POST will work if you simply remove the declarations from the serializer. This won't solve your problem unless you're willing to go without `write_only`, but it will give us more information.

Comment: To clarify, my last reply was in fact removing the field from `ArticleSerializer`, not just the POST request - and I still get the error since `category_id` is required

Comment: What your serializer should look like:

http://hastebin.com/egadakoxeb.py

Do not remove them from your POST request. JUST your serializer.

Comment: When I do that I get the following error by even looking at the browsable API: ImproperlyConfigured at /api/v1/articles/
Field name `sport_id` is not valid for model `Article`.